# Why did the piece of paper have "C - 16" written in it?

Tags: plot-explanation, breathe

In the last episode of *Breathe: Into the Shadows* (season 1), J, the split of Avinash Sabharwal, gives a piece of paper to Shirley as she is about to walk away. Later in that episode she is seen opening that paper and "C - 16" is written on it. What is that supposed to be? If that is a seat number then why is that given to Shirley?

Comment: https://www.hindustantimes.com/tv/breathe-into-the-shadows-ending-explained-is-abhishek-bachchan-s-j-back-what-does-c-16-mean/story-vCvPliO3c39PurFm2bKjmJ.html

Answer (score -1):

C-16 is the code word that J told Saiyami’s character he’d give her if he needed her help, in one of their chats in a hotel room.

Comment: So it is not clear yet, what help was he asking right?

Comment: How do we know that it's the codeword? Was it explained somewhere?

Comment: Can't remember which episode, but yes he explained it